# php cURL form post login then display site in embed tags

Tags: php, forms, curl, embed

I want to be able to log into a site (form POST) from my site and then display the logged in site on my site.

Will logging into the site with cURL (form POST) and on success display the site as if I was logged in on my site using the embed tag work? Is this the right way to do what I want?

Examples would be helpful.

Comment: you'd probably want an iframe, and you'd have to set up a full proxy to rewrite all resource references (img/script src, etc...) to point at your proxy rather than the original site's server.

Comment: @Marc B do you have any examples?

Comment: nope. it's not something you can simply dash off in 2 or 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

That can work if you add `<base>` tag pointing to the website you are displaying to load all css and js files with relative paths.

Also, if you store cookies in file or database, you might not even need to login every time.